# Docker - Nginx dynamic module is not getting added

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to build a nginx docker image with echo nginx third party module as a dynamic module using below dockefile

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
                gcc \
                libc-dev \
                make \
                openssl-dev \
                pcre-dev \
                zlib-dev \
                linux-headers \
                libxslt-dev \
                gd-dev \
                geoip-dev \
                git

RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O nginx.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf "nginx.tar.gz"

RUN git clone "https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module.git"
RUN ECHODIR="/usr/src/echo-nginx-module"

RUN cd nginx-$NGINX_VERSION && \
    ./configure --add-module=$ECHODIR && \
    make modules

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/objs/ngx_http_echo_module.so /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so

WORKDIR /usr/src

ADD ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The builder image got compiled successfully, but while copying the module from builder to child image getting the below error

`failed to compute cache key: "/usr/src/nginx-1.20.2/objs/ngx_http_echo_module.so" not found: not found`